# Optimize for loop with huge lists

Tags: python, algorithm, list, loops, optimization

I try to write an efficient code to deal with huge lists. I'm comparing several lists linked with locations.

**Theoretical lists :**

> Tx,Ty,Px,Py,Pz (Tx,Ty are locations and Px,Py,Pz are values of
>   parameters associated with these locations)

**Real lists :**

```
Rx,Ry,px,py,pz
```

> len(Tx) = 215 000 and len(Rx) = 68 000 000

The first thing I do is to cut Real lists with theoretical `maxTx`, `maxTy`, `minTx` and `minTy` :

```
 r=[index for index, value in enumerate(Rx) if value<=maxTx and value>=minTx]
 for p in range (len(r)):
        rx.append(Rx[r[p]]) (same for Ry,px,py, pz)
```

Then I do the same for y coordinates so I delimitate a square around theoretical locations ready for the comparison and now len(Rx) = 6 500 000

Now, I want to keep every real locations index answering a certain condition :

```
       for i in range (len(set(Tx))):
       l=[index for index,value in enumerate(set(Rx)) if value<=Tx[i]+d  and value>=Tx[i]-d]
              for j in range (len(l)):
              rrx.append(Rx[l[j]]) (same for Ry,px,py,pz)
```

Apparently, this is working as expected but it takes a long time to check every 215 000 values of Tx with 6 500 000 values of Rx. What I want is the index of Rx values respecting my condition so I only store it.

Then I check it with y locations with shorter lists ..

My final condition is :

```
    for n in range (len(Rrrx)):
        if sqrt((Tx[i]-Rx[n])**2+(Ty[i]-Ry[n])**2)<=d:
            Sx.append(Rx[n])
            Sy.append(Ry[n])
            Dif.append(sqrt((Tx[i]-Rx[n])**2+(Ty[i]-Ry[n])**2)
```

First, I just checked this condition but it was clearly too long to check every 215 000 values with 68 000 000 values, that's why I tried to reduce Real lists to the minimum before doing the comparison.

I hope this is understandable, Do you know another method to do it faster ? Thanks for your help

Comment: What type are the values in your lists?

Comment: One solution might be using `numpy` arrays instead of lists. Loading your lists into a `pandas.DataFrame` as columns and do the processing might help too. There are many functionalities provided by the both libraries that might support your application

Comment: The `sqrt` function is part of the bottleneck.  You don't need to calculate the actual distance if Δx or Δy is greater than d.  So a possible optimization would be something like this:  `if Tx[i]-Rx[n]<=d and Ty[i]-Ry[n]<=d and sqrt((Tx[i]-Rx[n])**2+(Ty[i]-Ry[n])**2)<=d:`  Short circuit evaluation would prevent the `sqrt` function from running unnecessarily.

Comment: My lists contain float numbers such as 789999.0. I'll check numpy opportunities.

Comment: If your numbers are simply floats, you should be using NumPy. Avoid explicit for-loops with NumPy, and explicite single-element comparisons when using NumPy: for the latter, for example, use boolean indexing using the comparisons.

Comment: @RickHitchcock No need to even call sqrt ever, just compare the square of the distances.  And when the actual distances are needed, python provides math.hypot.

Comment: @Niriel, great point.  Avoiding sqrt altogether should definitely speed things up.

Comment: The [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) stack exchange will  be more adapted for this question imho.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine a grid of size *d/2*.

Divide the *T* points into buckets according to which grid square they're in.  You can use a map from grid square to point.

Now, for each *R* point, you only need to check it against the *T* points in the 9 squares that are within distance *d* of it.